# Error using Microsoft Access Driver in Windows 7

Tags: vbscript, odbc, driver, windows-7-x64

I have a vbs which connect with a access data base (.mdb). In my windows XP works perfect, but in my windows 7 x64 I have a problem with the drivers...

This is the code that I have:

```
Set MyConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set MyConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
MdbFilePath = "c:\mis documentos\fusion\fusion.mdb"

'The error point to the next line
MyConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & MdbFilePath & ";"

'querys'    
SQL_versionlocal = "SELECT versionlocal.version FROM versionlocal;"

SQL_version = "SELECT version.version FROM version;"

Set RSL = MyConn.Execute(SQL_versionlocal)
'  Wscript.echo "Versión local " & RSL("version") 
versionlocal = RSL("version")
```

This is the issue:

```
[Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Can not find the data source name and no default driver specified.
```

Any tip or help will be appreciated, and if you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your Microsoft-Office 32-Bit or 64-Bit?
You may try running the script with the 32-Bit wscript\cscript found at C:\Windows\Syswow64\Wscript.exe

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realized! Thanks! :)