# VBScript Oracle Driver version requirement

Tags: vbscript, windows-7-x64

I am having the same Issue as [Error using Microsoft Access Driver in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969892/error-using-microsoft-access-driver-in-windows-7)

I have: 
      **Windows 7 with 64 bit, 
     *Oracle-OraClient 11g Home 2 32 bit driver*, and 
     Office 2013 32 bit.**

In this version I keep getting an ODBC Driver manager error even if I already added the DSN on the odbcad32.exe from the SysWOW64 directory and made sure that the vbscripts is opening using the wscript.exe from SysWow64 as well.

the same vbscript run on but the Access 2013 does not recognize the Oracle Driver
      **Windows 7 with = 64 bit, 
     *Oracle-OraClient 11g Home 2 = 64 bit driver* and 
     Office 2013 = 32 bit.**

```
Option Explicit 
Dim i, cnt, r, c, nc, v, vname, vinvoice, vamount, vdate, vlowdate, vin, vpo, vcompany 
Dim ofs, oFolder, oFiles, sFile, sFileName, sExtension 
Dim iSqlDetail, vRawISql , vsqldetail 
Dim oExcel, oWorkbook, oWorksheet 
Dim oAdo, sSql, oRs, aRs, oTs 
Dim vPath , sPath , sOutput 
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
oExcel.Visible = True 
Set oAdo = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")      
oAdo.ConnectionString= "User ID=uname;Password=pwd;DSN=MYDSN" 
oAdo.Open 
Set ofs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set ofolder = ofs.GetFolder(".")
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with Oracle on Win7. As a workaround, I had to use `ojdbc6.jar` and write a Java code to take in the sql query from VBS. I would be interested in knowing how to get this working from VBS only.

Comment: I do not know how to do a Java code :(

Comment: @PankajJaju can you show me the Java code you did? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is the Java code that fetches the data from DB and stores it in clipboard -- since my recordset would never be big, so I can get away with it :-)

**Java Code** - compile it as classfile

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.*;

public class BookNameHelper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORAD01:5500:CALT3", "schemaname","password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                String selectstr = "select bookname from bookstore where publisher="+"'"+args[0]+"'";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectstr);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String BookName = rs.getString("bookname");
                    Clipboard clip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                    StringSelection testData;
                    testData = new StringSelection(traderName);
                    clip.setContents(testData, testData);
                    System.out.println(BookName);
                }
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

**VBS** - You can then use VBScript to read the dataset from clipboard and store it in a variable ... something like the below

```
Set oHtml = CreateObject("htmlfile")
SuffixText = oHtml.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")
Set oHtml = Nothing
```